# as3 Tile game - If character steps over tile, do something

Tags: actionscript-3, tile, event-listener

So im working on a tile game for school and not very familiar with programming so apologies if the answer is obvious.

Using an array ive created a map with different tiles- what i want is so that when the character walks across a certain array then something happens - eg: restart the game

My code is all in one .as file :

```js
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class main2 extends MovieClip {
        public function main2() {
            // Create map

            var mapWidth = 10;
            var mapHeight = 10;
            var tileSide = 32;
            var totalTiles = mapWidth * mapHeight;
            var myMap: Array = [
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
            ];

            for (var i: int = 0; i < mapHeight; i++) {
                for (var u: int = 0; u < mapWidth; u++) {
                    var cell: MovieClip = new tile();
                    cell.gotoAndStop(myMap[i][u] + 1);
                    cell.x = tileSide * u
                    cell.y = tileSide * i
                    addChild(cell);
                }
            }
   
   // Hero management

            var heroSpawnX = 1
            var heroSpawnY = 1

            var character: hero = new hero();
            addChild(character)
            character.x = heroSpawnX * tileSide
            character.y = heroSpawnY * tileSide

            var heroX = heroSpawnX
            var heroY = heroSpawnY    
   

            // Basic movement

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, movement);

            function movement(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
                if (event.keyCode == 40 && myMap[heroY + 1][heroX] != 1) {
                    character.gfx.rotation = 0
                    character.y += tileSide
                    heroY++ //Down
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 38 && myMap[heroY - 1][heroX] != 1) {
                    character.gfx.rotation = 180
                    character.y -= tileSide
                    heroY-- //Up
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 39 && myMap[heroY][heroX + 1] != 1) {
                    character.gfx.rotation = 270
                    character.x += tileSide
                    heroX++ //Right
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 37 && myMap[heroY][heroX - 1] != 1) {
                    character.gfx.rotation = 90
                    character.x -= tileSide
                    heroX-- //Left
                }
            } //movement function
   
        } // behind this line
    }

}
```

In my array there is a '2' in the second row. I want my character to walk across  that tile and 'die'- but more just restart from his spawn postion ([1][1]). I assume an event listener would be needed but after googleing some codes- still can not get it to work.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: if you accept this answer and my previous answer,please accept them by clicking on that tick at top left of my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add these pieces to your code:

this function returns the number of the specified tile:

```
function getNumberAt(tileX:uint,tileY:uint){
    var value:uint=myMap[tileX][tyleY];
    return value
}
```

note that your indices for this function should start from zero( if you want tile at first horizontal and second vertical,you should `getNumberAt(0,1)`

now replace your function:

```
  function movement(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
            if (event.keyCode == 40 && myMap[heroY + 1][heroX] != 1) {
                character.gfx.rotation = 0
                character.y += tileSide
                heroY++ //Down
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 38 && myMap[heroY - 1][heroX] != 1) {
                character.gfx.rotation = 180
                character.y -= tileSide
                heroY-- //Up
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 39 && myMap[heroY][heroX + 1] != 1) {
                character.gfx.rotation = 270
                character.x += tileSide
                heroX++ //Right
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 37 && myMap[heroY][heroX - 1] != 1) {
                character.gfx.rotation = 90
                character.x -= tileSide
                heroX-- //Left
            }
            trace(getNumberAt(heroX,heroY))//test getNumberAt function


            if(getNumberAt(heroX,heroY)==2){
                //type your code for death here
            }

        }
```

I  h☻p e  this   helps !

Comment: sorry about the previous question. I can't seem to get this to work, ive copied the code word for word minus the typo ( i think it was a typo anyways, in the second line). I wrote like trace("hello") in the if statement just to see the output, but nothing. Im fairly certain i just havent put it in right. Do you have any insight?

Comment: In this situations, Inspect the code ! use trace to find out, the problem is from `getNumber` or someWhere else.I edited the code.

Comment: thanks for that I figured it out using another way which was very simlar to your way minus the function. I appreciate the help ahaha i have no doubt that your answer would have worked if it werent for my lack my skill :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :)

Comment: The function `getNumberAt` cannot work because it is treating `myMap` like a 1 dimensional array. `myMap` is a 2 dimensional array though.